# How to solve the problem of dimentions after Turning the Return_Sequence off in LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am a beginner in Keras and would like to modify this code. However,I am getting an error about output dimensions.

This is part of a code that works fine:

```
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(tr_in.shape[1],tr_in.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(tr_in, tr_out,validation_data=(val_in, val_out))
```

The training and validation input and output matrices are 3D. 
I want to turn off the 'Return sequence'. But I am getting an error as follows:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 16, 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is happening is when you change return_sequences from True to False, you are reducing the output from the LSTM layer to be 2 dimensional - in particular only having one output at the end of processing all of the timesteps.  This is now in conflict with what the fit is expecting because the "target" data (tr_out) is 3D.  I believe the return_sequences=True outputs one result per timestep which looks like there are 16 timesteps per sample in your case.  I think you'll need to make the tr_out dimensions match (become 2D) when return_sequences=False.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but you could potentially create a subset using regular python/numpy processing like this:  y_train_sub=np.squeeze(y_train[:,-1,:])  or something similar, depending on the meaning of the y-target data.  I hope this helps.